# Cannot resolve the issue for the weasis maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I do Run AS> Maven Install in eclipse .. I get the following error.... Please help

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:bundle (default-bundle) on project weasis-imageio-codec-windows-x86: Error calculating classpath for project MavenProject: org.weasis.imageio:weasis-imageio-codec-windows-x86:1.2-b04 @ /usr/local/AT_Dev_Env/Amritam/Other projects/Weasis-1.2.6/weasis-imageio/weasis-imageio-codec-windows-x86/pom.xml: The JAR/ZIP file (/home/sreejith/.m2/repository/org/weasis/thirdparty/com/sun/media/jai-lib/1.1.4-b05/jai-lib-1.1.4-b05.jar) seems corrupted, error: error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: delete the file '/home/sreejith/.m2/repository/org/weasis/thirdparty/com/sun/media/jai-lib/1.1.4-b05/jai-lib-1.1.4-b05.jar' and try again. Maybe your local maven repository really is corrupted.

Comment: Tried it ...didn't help...

Comment: Hmm, and the other obvious reasons are also not an issue (write permissions (meaning correct user is accessing your home directory); disk is not full)? 
When I get errors like this, I usually delete my whole .m2 repository and try again. Maybe a big hammer, but repairing something there is usually not worth the effort.

Comment: it seems the jar that is provided by the remote repository is correpted.I tried by downloading directly from the url ...no luck..